# Conditional Probability of a group of Mice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, data-analysis

There are six female and four male mice in a group of 10. One of the female
mice and two of the male mice have a particular disease. Suppose that two mice
are selected at random from the group without replacement. The following
events are defined:
A: Both mice are female.
B: Exactly one of the mice has the disease.

If exactly one of the mice has the disease, what is the probability that
both are female?

Computing P(Both mice are female) $= {6 \over 10} \times {5 \over 9} = {1 \over 3}$

And P(Exactly one has disease) $= {3 \over 10} \times {7 \over 9} = {7 \over 30}$

So we use conditional probability to find P(A|B) which equals = $
P(A|B) = {{1 \over 3} + {7 \over 30} \over {7 \over 30} } = 2 {3 \over 7} $

Which is obviously incorrect as the probability cannot exceed 1, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, you computed $P(B)$ incorrectly (you computed the probability that the first one is sick and the second healthy).  More seriously, your formula for $P(A|B)$ does not make sense.  $\frac {P(A)+P(B)}{P(B)}$ is always $≥1$.  You should use $P(A|B)=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: You've computed the probability that exactly one mouse is sick wrong -- what you have computed is the probability that the _first_ mouse selected is diseased and the _second_ is not, but it could also be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \text{ and } B)}{P(B)}$.

So you need $P(A \text{ and } B)$ as well. This is not the sum (which is an overestimation of the probability $P(A \text{ or } B)$).

Note that $P(B)$ is computed incorrectly in your case. It is $\frac{\binom{1}{3}\binom{1}{7}}{\binom{10}{2}}$. $P(A)$ is not needed.

To compute $P(A \cap B)$: we have to pick the only sick female mouse and one healthy female mouse, with probability $\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{10}{2}}$.

Now use the formula.